# "Restoring previous versions of Windows" error loop in Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, updates

For the past week, Windows Update has constantly notified me that it will proceed in updating my system and will require a restart.

Once the computer attempts to boot, it outputs the error "restoring the previous version of Windows" and then boots normally. Shortly after it notifies me about the update and asks for a reboot again (the loop continues.) **I have tried creating a .bat file to turn off the service every X minutes and deferring updates however possible.**

After about a week of fighting with the update manager it eventually rebooted and now my m.2 drive is not even recognized as a boot device. **Now when I boot from my main drive (which houses the OS) it not only produces the error but does not even restore the previous version correctly. It just continues to retry to restoring the previous state with no end. Has anyone had this issue and do you know how to remediate it?**

I am using **Windows 10 Home and an m.2 drive**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fully re-image the machine, what a pain.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  What you posted here as an answer is a lot briefer than your comment on Tom's answer.  It's so short, it may get automatically pulled into the review queue just because of that.  You might want to beef it up with info from your comment.  :-)